# PHP wont redirect from log-in form

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, authentication

I am making an html login page which will submit a form to a php page to check to see if user details lie in an established username access database. 
If the username and password correspond to a row in the database, the php redirects to an mainpage (mainpage.html), otherwise it redirects back to the login page (LOGINPAGE.html).

The if function I have used to achieve this in my php script is as follows:

```
if(odbc_fetch_row($DetailCheckExec)) //If username corresponds with password
    header('Location: mainpage.html');
    else 
        header('Location: LOGINPAGE.html');
```

The problem is, the php doesn't seem to redirect. **Even if I simplify my code to simply redirect, nothing changes.** i.e.

```
<?php
header("Location: LOGINPAGE.html");
exit;
?>
```

won't work either.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please enable errors by placing this code at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you see

Comment: Please do not walk away after asking a question. You have comments that need to be addressed and now the chance for users to help you is dwindling away. Always hang around to answer questions others may have,

Comment: My apologies. I have found the problem to be my wamp server which was set up correctly.

Answer (score -1):

well i dont know the function "(odbc_fetch_row($DetailCheckExec)" but there's a step by step login that I made i hope it works

```
if ((isset($_POST['user'])) and (isset($_POST['password'])))
{//checks if the inputs in the form are empty
        //sets two variables with the value of the imputs
        $usuario = $_POST['user'];
        $clave = $_POST['password'];
        //then selects the row where the values are equal in the database
        $consulta = "SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM `usuarios` 
                        WHERE usuario = '$usuario' and contrasena = '$clave'";

        $resultados=mysqli_query($con,$consulta);

        while(($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))){
                $vpeso = $fila['peso'];
                $vestatura = $fila['estatura'];
                $vusuario = $fila['usuario'];
                }

        if(($resultados) AND ((isset($vusuario)) and ($vusuario <> '') )){
            //starts session
            session_start();

            //stablishes the user in the session
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;


          //if the user doesn't exist it will bring to signup.php for example
          }else{
          header("Location: signup.php");
        }

}
```

well I hope it works, sorry for not changing the variable names haha

Comment: This code is very insecure and I do not recommend anyone use it.